# Search location and activity

Tags: search

What is the best way to search in a database for a request such as 'Hong Kong Jazz club' ?

The database has a table with the following fields :
- place name
- location (country, city, district)
- activity

Hong Kong will be found in the field 'location' and jazz club in the field 'activity'.
The issue is on how to analyze the text entered by the user 'Hong Kong Jazz club' and return relevant results.

Maybe it is too complicated to search this kind of thing in one field (and that's why Foursquare uses 2 fields, one for the activity and one for the location).

Comment: Can users enter radom text like "Jazz clubs Hong kong", "Jazz Hong kong"?

Comment: What database do you mean? Do you mean full text search?

Comment: Ewald, yes, users type what they want / Serge, MySQL database, full text search.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @input = 'hong kong jazz club';

SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE @input LIKE CONCAT('%', Location, '%')
  AND @input LIKE CONCAT('%', Activity, '%');
```

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11ffc/1